# Vibration modes and specific heat for $CO_2$

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

I'm having a confusion regarding the molar specific heat (at constant volume) for the carbon dioxide. Suppose we admit that this quantity is related to the degrees of freedom of the molecule by the equation:
$\begin{equation}\small{c}_v=f\frac{R}{2}\end{equation}$
So, assuming $CO_2$ is a linear molecule, it has three translational degs of freedom, and two rotational. As for the vibrational modes, we assume that $f'=2(3N-5)$ is valid, $N$ being the number of atoms, and, again, assuming linearity. Therefore we would have $8$ contributions for the energy from vibrational modes.

Assuming equipartition of energy, the specific heat at constant volume for the carbon dioxide would be $\frac{13R}{2}$, which disagrees with the experimental measured value $\small{c}_V\simeq\frac{9R}{2}$.

I know about breaking of equipartition due to the quantum nature of vibration. Even though, seems quite arbitrary, and since this was given to me in a problem set, seems unlikely.

Is there a not "loooking up the table" way of getting the correct result? Some vibrational mode contribution I could've ignore beforehand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice in the graph of the answer to the duplicate that near 500 K, $\mathcal{C}_P/2\approx 11R/2$, which corresponds to $\mathcal{C}_V/2\approx 9R/2$. This means that you must have been asked to compute the molar specific heat at a particular temperature (perhaps *room* temperature, which is near-ish to 500 K).